# Failure to import python package 'primers'

Tags: python, import, pip

I think I'm having a simple import command problem, or possibly a permissions problem?

I installed the package "primers" with `pip3 install primers` as per the docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/primers/)
It's definitely installed, because it runs in the CLI

but in python, the command `from primers import primers` results in the error
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'primers'"

`which python` and `which primers` point to adjacent locations in bin/

so... what should i be trying to try to fix this and import this package? ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check these:

1. Please make sure you are in the same environment
2. check if the module is installed in your env: pip3 list
3. check your default python version.

Comment: `pip3 list` includes primers, but in python `help("modules")` does not include primers, so this appears to be an environment issue, somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the pip3 uninstall primers command then use pip3 install primers command. Answer me back if you still have a error

Comment: Still displaying the error

Comment: oh, It must be a problem with the package, I have installed ursina and that doesn't work for me, I later found out that ursina is only for windows, not for mac. Maybe that is the same case for you?